# What is the difference in meaning of a voltage signal and current signal?

Tags: voltage, current, signal

This might sound like a crazy bad question. But I'm wondering even though current and voltage inevitability co-exist, why do we use the term for one concept(current or voltage)? If there is a signal out there somewhere, it is both current and voltage at the same time. But we name only one of its property.

Is that about knowing one of them well? I mean lets say we have an amplifier and if we only set the amplifier with a "known voltage gain" we call it voltage amplifier and if we set it with a "known current gain" we call it current amplifier? Or is that because the nature of the input signal?

Could you give an input signal example and explain why it is called a voltage or current signal?

EDIT: My confusion didn't settle. Lets say we have a single stage amplifier. And it has an input and output. So when you look at such circuit and its input and output, what makes you to conclude it is amplifying a current input signal or a voltage input signal? What is the method to name the type of the input signal? Imagine it is increasing both. I still don't understand how to distinguish.

EDIT2: imagine a typical common emitter stable biased single npn bjt transistor amplifier. such as: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amplifier9.gif?81223b . the base voltage in this case is "bias voltage + small signal voltage - emitter voltage". and the input current current is very low. now look at the output. output voltage increased. okay. but wait.. output current also increased and became "beta*Ibase". So now the input current increased and the input voltage also increased.. is this a current or voltage amplifier? and if it is X amplifier does that mean the input signal is X signal. (X is current or voltage)

Comment: Because that is what we are intrested in; for a voltage signal we measure its voltage and don't care what current was needed to produce this voltage.

Comment: A signal is something which contains information of some sort. If you are somehow controlling voltage to represent information, then it's a voltage signal. If you are adjusting current through a loop to signify the information, then that is a current signal.

Comment: If you were to add a schematic of the amplifier you speak of, we would likely be able to tell you which it is and why.

Comment: a BJT transistor is a "current amplifier", with it's default/standard behaviour and physical properties

Comment: but it has a voltage gain it also amplifies the voltage.. ahh am confused..

Comment: no, they have current gain. You can "generate" a voltage over a resistor by pushing current through it - this is how you can create a voltage proportional to some reference..

Comment: but why? both current and voltage has gain. you are saying it is current amplifier. does that also mean that the input is a "current signal" since it is amplifying current?

Comment: The transistor in that amplifier sees input voltage waveform (in the form of current through a known resistor) and adjusts it's output current through the Collector-Emitter. The collector-emitter acts like a variable resistor, and paired with R_L above the BJT it acts like a dynamic/adjustable resistor divider from the 30V rail to 0V.

Comment: doesnt make sense to me. i still dont get why we choose one particular naming here when both are increased,

Comment: The circuit does essentially "amplify" the representation of the input voltage by producing a larger version of it on the output side, however an NPN BJT itself is a "current amplifier". The use of resistors and Ohms law allows you to make it act as something that works as a voltage amplifier but you cannot make something out of nothing - there is already 30V available!

Comment: and what do you call the input signal? current signal or voltage signal?

Comment: In the example circuit you showed, it's a "small signal" voltage of some type, in a sinusoidal waveform. But remember the voltage is converted to a current by the base resistor, and the base current then changes how the BJT behaves, which in turn finally changes the output voltage - the design is such that there is a voltage on the output which is input * gain.

Comment: oh my god it is much more complicated than i thought. after i asked this question the answers made me dizzy. i really have issues with naming these concepts here. everything is increasing and both we have lower input current and voltage. but still we call it a voltage signal and current amplifier.

Comment: You are confusing circuit design/behaviour with component properties - an NPN BJT is a current amplifier, but remember current and voltage are very simply related by V = IR. All you need to do is some tricks with resistors and you can convert between a current and a voltage. Internally, the circuit uses current through resistors, to make the overall input and output results act like a voltage amplifier. Put 1V in, get 2V out, for example - but the inner workings are by current multiplication, and the output voltage gain is set by the resistors.

Comment: i know the relation between current and voltage and many other concepts. i also understand how that amplifier works. but when it comes to naming i cannot find a standard way of thinking where i can apply the same methodology and can say: ok this is a current signal because... and this is a voltage amplifier because,,,. im totally lost..

Comment: you need to think about where the signal is coming from and who/what is making it. If an op-amp is producing a small signal from 0-1V which is a representation of frequency (for example) from 0-100Hz, and you feed that into a 'voltage amplifier circuit' to get 0-5V, then all of this makes sense (the gain would be 5 by the way). If you instead chose to make 0-100Hz as 4-20mA signal like is often found in industrial sensors, then you would be making a "current" signal not a voltage one. The receiving end of this current signal would most likely convert it to a voltage and then amplify.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a signal, generally one of voltage or current is what is being controlled, and the other is a bi-product that is dependent on the load.

Consider a normal digital logic signal running between two CMOS chips on the same board.  That's a voltage signal.  Only the voltage is specified.  Not only is the current not specified, but it can vary hugely and isn't known by the designers of the transmitting chip since it depends on the load the receiver presents.

If the only receiver in the above example is a CMOS chip, then very little current will flow in steady state.  The load is almost purely capacitive, so current will flow in short blips when the logic level is changed.  If instead this signal drives a LED and resistor so as to light the LED when high, then the current will be very different from the previous case.  It will again be very different if the LED is wired between power and this signal (lit on logic low) instead of ground and this signal (lit on logic high).

Sometimes the signal value is encoded in the current, in which case the voltage ends up what it ends up.  A common example is the industrial 4-20 mA sensor standard.  The data is encoded by allowing from 4 to 20 mA to flow, but the voltage can vary over a range.  In fact, this is called the *compliance range*, with a larger range allowing for more flexible use of the device.  In this case, you can't look at the voltage to get the value being transmitted.

Comment: i edited my question.

Answer (score 5):

Picture two things: an electrical source, and a load that connects to the (two pins of) the source.

The relation between voltage, current, and the load is fixed by Ohms law: current = voltage / resistance.

Consequently, when the load is unknown, the source can choose between 'fixing' (setting, determining) the voltage OR fixing the current, but not both.

Hence when we want the source to convey information, it can do so either by its output voltage, OR by its output current. And that is how we name the source.

Comment: Lets say we have a single stage amplifier. And it has an input and output. So when you look at such circuit and its input and output, what makes you to conclude it is amplifying current signal or voltage signal. Imagine it is increasing both. I still don't understand how to distinguish.

Comment: i edited my question,

Comment: An amplifier is *designed* to have either a voltage (low impedance, high possible current) or current (high impedance, high possible voltage) output. Independently, it can have a voltage (high impedance) or current (low impedance) input. So you look at the input and output stages, and you recognise how they are designed (for low or high impedance).

Comment: "voltage (low impedance, high possible current) or current (high impedance, high possible voltage) output." is there some mistyping here?

Comment: No, not that I see any.

Comment: if the output impedance is low how can it be called a voltage output? since high current flows

Comment: I suggest you read some basic texts on electronics. Low impedance is the key characteristic of a voltage source.

Comment: ok i mixed it with the input impedance of the next stage that couples with the output of the amplifier

Comment: okay here is the example circuit: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amplifier9.gif?81223b Now Im going to follow your logic. Since output impedance is zero (Vout doesnt have a resistor connected), it must be called a "current amplifier". And since it has high input impedance(Ibase is very small) it is a "voltage signal".. Did I understand you?

Comment: @user16307 What do you mean Vout doesn't have a resistor? What are RL and RE? (I'm not familiar with analog circuits so maybe RE doesn't count, but I'd be very surprised if RL didn't)

Comment: in two port network model if a device has high input impedance and low output impedance they call it voltage amplifier or voltage controlled voltage source. if instead the network has low input impedance and high output impedance they call it current amplifier or current controlled current source. in the circuit i provided can we apply the same logic? Input impedance is high between base and emitter. Right? What is output impedance here? Rc?

Comment: should i go and study g and h parameters to understand this. is there an easier way?

Comment: The common-emitter configuration that you show is a compromise: reasonable input impedance, output impedance, voltage amplification, and current amplification. The terms you use are abstractions, real circuits are sometimes a good aproximation. This one is not. But is is a good compromise, and it has good power amplification.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, a voltage signal can have any load across it and it will still output approximately the same voltage. Conversely, a current signal regardless of load will give approximately the same current.

An example of a voltage signal would be a bench-top power supply. You set it to a voltage and it tries to output as much current as necessary to maintain that voltage.

An example of a current signal would be something like an inductor with a collapsing magnetic field. It results in a temporary pseudo constant current. If you put a high resistance load across it, you'll get a very high voltage.

No signal is truly a voltage or current signal entirely. We simply name them that way because certain signals are closer to an ideal current or ideal voltage source.

---

EDIT:
You'll know based on the input of the amplifier. If the input is **high impedance** (a gate of a mosfet), then you're likely amplifying a **voltage** because a large current isn't meant to pass through a high impedance. If the amplifier is setup with a **low impedance** input, then you're amplifying a **current**. An example of this would be something like a current mirror/multiplier. In this case, the input is the drain of mosfets or collector of bjts which is low impedance.

Something to note is that most amplifiers amplify voltage so if you want to measure a current and amplify that, it's sometimes converted to a voltage through a resistor (or other means) and then amplified through an op-amp.

Comment: i made an edit to my question.

Comment: imagine a typical common emitter stable biased single npn bjt transistor amplifier. such as:http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amplifier9.gif?81223b . the base voltage in this case is "bias voltage + small signal voltage". and the input current current is very low. now look at the output. output voltage increased. okay. but wait.. output current also increased and became "beta*Ibase".  So now the input current increased and the input voltage also increased.. is this a current or voltage amplifier?

Comment: @user16307 a common emitter amplifier has its current gain based on beta and the voltage gain based on the ratio of Rc/Re. In this case you have a voltage gain of 10 and a current gain of 100. In this case, you could say it's acting as more of current gain amp than a voltage gain amp. As I mentioned before, there is no such thing as an ideal current or voltage amplifier or an ideal current or voltage signal. Does it matter what you call it? You could increase Rc to 100k and it would then be more of a voltage gain amp than a current gain amp.

Comment: are you saying if beta is greater than voltage gain it is called s current amplifier?

Comment: @user16307 If Ai > Av then it's a current amplifier. If Av > Ai then it's a voltage amplifier. Both are nothing more than attempts at descriptive names. If Ai = Av, then you have a perfectly equal voltage and current amplifier.

Comment: also u say bjt is current amp. but i saw audio amp stages with bjts which they call voltage amplifier.. are u sure?

Comment: @user16307 notice I mentioned that you can easily change a common emitter amplifier into a voltage or current amp based on the biasing resistors. BJT is modeled as a current amp. The topology and biasing resistors are really what determine whether it's more of a voltage or current amp though.

Comment: ok i give up it doesnt make sense to me

Comment: @user16307 what exactly doesn't make sense? An amplifier is not a single component. An amplifier is the entire circuit or subsection of a circuit. Do you understand what Ai and Av are?

Comment: Note:  Many bench power supplies have both constant current and constant voltage mode. They'll use CC mode below a certain voltage, and CV mode below a certain current.

Comment: @immibis True. The cheaper ones like I have at home do not :(

Answer (score 2):

A signal is a means of communication.  You decide how you're going to communicate, and then you communicate using that method - whether it's by changing current, changing voltage, changing impedance, two tin cans and a bit of wet string, or whatever.  One end talks, and one end listens.

In order to communicate with voltage, you put enough current into the load to get the voltage you need.  In order to communicate with current, you put enough voltage into the load to get the current you need.  In order to communicate with impedance, your listener applies a voltage and looks at the current, or vice versa.

Why you would choose a particular signalling method is a matter of engineering judgement, looking at the benefits and disadvantages of each.